# Default parameter must be compile-time constant

Tags: c#, datetime, compiler-errors

I want to create a method that has optional parameters. The program I am writing needs these to be in DateTime form. My current method declaration is

```
public void UpdateTable(int month = DateTime.Now.Month, int year = DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        // Code here.
    }
```

However, I am getting this error "Default parameter value for 'month' must be a compile-time constant."

How can I fix this error? Do I need to set these values outside the method, before calling it?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is dependent on when it is called during execution, so it's not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to set it beforehand, I think you'll have to pass in a different set of defaults:

```
    public void UpdateTable(int month = -1, int year = -1)
    {
        if (month == -1) month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        if (year == -1) year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` will be different, of course, each time the program is run -- so it can't be used as a default value.

One way to approach this would be with overloaded functions with different parameter counts.

```
public void UpdateTable(int month, int year)
{
    // Code here.
}

public void UpdateTable(int month)
{
    // fill in the current year
    UpdateTable(month, DateTime.Now.Year);
}

public void UpdateTable()
{
    // fill in the current month / year
    UpdateTable(DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. As the error indicates, the default value of an optional parameter must be determined at compile time.

You can use a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (`int?`), like this:

```
public void UpdateTable(int? month = null, int? year = null)
{
    month = month ?? DateTime.Now.Month;
    year = year ?? DateTime.Now.Year;
    // Code here.
}
```

But I'd recommend making overloads, like this:

```
public void UpdateTable(int month, int year)
{
    // Code here.
}
public void UpdateTable(int month)
{
    UpdateTable(month, DateTime.Now.Year);
}
public void UpdateTable()
{
    UpdateTable(DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year);
}
```

Comment: What about if you want to be able to pass in either just the month or just the year?  You can't have two overloads that take the same parameter set.  That's why defaults are so useful; you can have more control over the parameters sent.

Comment: @Francine Yes, it depends on exactly what kind of API the OP is building. That's why I included both options. If it were my code, I would also consider having two different methods, `UpdateTableMonth` and `UpdateTableYear` to completely avoid confusion, or even better, a single method that takes a `DateTime` instead, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

.Now is not a constant, so you cannot use it for default values.

I'd recommend defaulting to null, and then if the value is null, then get the default value during runtime.

```
public void UpdateTable(int? month = null, int? year = null)
{
   month = month ?? DateTime.Now.Month;
   year = year ?? DateTime.Now.Year;
   // Code here.
}
```

Comment: what does this line do?
    month = month ?? DateTime.Now.Month?;

Comment: @Ultra are you asking about the null coalescing operator (??)?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: ?? // In summary: If the left operand is not null, then it returns the left operand.  If the left operand is null, then it returns the right operand.  So, for the "month = month ?? DateTime.Now.Month;" line, if month is null, it sets month to DateTime.Now.Month, and if month is not null, then it stays the same.

Comment: @Ben Sorry for not being specific. That was what I was asking about. Thank you for answering!